# Cannot analyze multple VS Solutions via SonarQube integrated with TFS 2012 build

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I followed the instructions on the "SonarQube Setup Guide for .NET Users" (http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/sq-setup-guide-for-dotnet-users.html) to setup a SonarQube 5.1.2 server and integrated with TFS 2012. Even though the document describes how to integrate SonarQube with TFS 2013 XAML builds and TFS 2015 Build vNext, I was able to somewhat integrate it with TFS 2012 XAML build. Here are the sequence of steps in the TFS 2012 XAML.

1. call InvokeProcess build activity (with WorkingDirecotry set to the directory containing the VS Solution file to be compiled such as `C:\Builds\...\ClassLibrary3` to call `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin ...` (MSBuild SonarQube Runner version 1.0.1)
2. Call Microsoft MSBuild activity to compile 1 or more VS Solutions such as `C:\Builds\...\ClassLibrary3\ClassLibrary3.sln`
3. call InvokeProcess build activity (with WorkingDirecotry set to the directory containing the VS Solution file previously compiled) to call `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end`

The problem is that I can only analyze one compiled VS Solution even if multiple VS Solutions are compiled. This is because the working directory must be the same when calling `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` and `MSBuild`. The MSBuild activity's working directory is set to where the VS Solution file is located but will differ for each VS Solution compiled but `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` can only specify one working directory. Is there a way to analyze multiple VS Solutions? I don't think there's a way to change MSBuild activity's working directory is there? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to proceed is be have one project in SonarQube for each of your solution, and use the Portfolio Management plugin (commercial) to perform the aggregation of all these projects on the server side to offer the big picture. See http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/ & on Nemo how it integrates all Apache projects for example: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index?id=Apache

Another way would be to craft a *.proj file that will include all other projects to build.

Another way, which I wouldn't recommend, is to invoke MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin for every solution that you build, then movie the contents of every `.sonarqube\out` folders to a single one (aggregate it), and call MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end from that location.

Another way would be to upgrade to TFS 2015, and check how its MSBuild task behaves.

Comment: Thank Dinesh. We're actually planning to upgrade to TFS 2015 but won't occur til next year. Using sandbox TFS 2015 environment and the instructions, I was able to create a TFS 2015 Build vNext to have SonarQube analyze multiple VS Solutions. Unfortunately, we have to dig into build log for "Command Line" build step to get link to SonarQube result. With TFS 2013 XAML builds, the SonarQube result link is somehow displayed in Build Summary.

I also thought about combining multiple .sonarqube\out folders to single folder but seems painful to do as you stated.

Comment: I'll take a look at the Portfolio Management plugin tool. Anyways, thanks for your help

Another option is that our TFS 2012 customized XAML can call devenv.exe instead of MSBuild activity to compile VS Solutions where working directory is where devenv.exe is at so I can use that location for MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe working directory. The problem with calling DevEnv.exe is that we won't be able to run automated tests (MSTest). Also, unfortunately, we have hardcoded to call VS 2010 DevEnv.exe...oops.